If $|S|=n$, series related to the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq S$.
While solving
if $|S|=n$, find the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq S$, I derived this interesting series
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{n!}{i!\left(n-i\right)!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\frac{\left(n-i\right)!}{j!\left(n-i-j\right)!}\right).$$
My teacher said the answer can be computed by $3^n$. Does that mean this series is equal to $3^n$? If so, how?

Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural start might be to compute the sum explicitly for small $n$.  After that, use the combinatorial interpretation of the sum.

Does this answer your question? Cardinality of set containing true order relations from a power set It proves that the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ s.t. $A\subseteq B\subseteq S$ (obviously equal to your double sum) equals $3^n$.

If your question was to find a non-combinatorial proof, I'd look at induction on $n$.

You should write the formula using binomial coefficients ($\binom{n}{i}=\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$, then use the Binomial formula to simplify the sum (alternatively, the Multinomial formula)

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234588
